# Why is "Pens" option greyed out in my Word 2016?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Oh and I checked out the "Customise Ribbons" tab too. I don't have a "Draw" option at all.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Do you have a pen type device? You may need to [repair office](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ink-tools-grayed-out-in-microsoft-word-and/163301f2-ff32-4e38-94cd-0200e77cb20d).

Comment: You should also verify the pen is working in the first place.

Comment: Another option: `In Word, you must be in Print layout to draw with ink. If the Draw tab is grayed out so that you can't select a pen, go the View tab and select Print Layout. ; then you can select a pen to draw with. Tap again to open the menu of Thickness and Color options for the pen.` https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/draw-and-write-with-ink-in-office-6d76c674-7f4b-414d-b67f-b3ffef6ccf53

Comment: Did you enable Pen and Ink in Windows 10 Settings under Devices?

Comment: @Mokubai I have a toughbook which is a 2-in-1 laptop which comes with a stylus. I tried repairing. Made no difference. I checked the Print Layout thingy too, it is in print layout. Still no change

Comment: @Ramhound The pen is working

Comment: @John I'm running windows 7

Comment: Do you have an inserted text box? Try inserting a text box, tap the text box and use it. In addition, could you select a line? You can choose the line first.

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT i tried that, still not working mate